Can we have a theory that interpret $\sf ZFC$, proves existence of an infinite set, and yet prove all of its sets being Dedekind finite?
If we start with axioms of $\sf ZF$ replace the axiom of Infinity with an axiom stating the existence of a set that doesn't have an injection to a von Neumann natural, and replace the axiom of Power sets by the axiom of unbounded cardinality, that is for each set $x$ there is a set $y$ such that $x$ is injective to $y$ but $y$ not injective to $x$.

Is it consistent with this theory to have all its sets being Dedekind finite?


Can this theory interpret $\sf ZFC$, through interpreting $L$ within it?


The answer to the question in the title, which is quite different from the question in the question, is yes: e.g., take $\mathrm{ZF_{fin}+Con_{ZFC}}$.

@EmilJeřábek, OK, I've changed the title to better suit the question.

What do you mean by constructing $L$ if you don't have $\omega$?

@JoelDavidHamkins, I thought $\omega$ could be interpreted, even though not provable in the system.

But then you wouldn't be constructing $L$, but interpreting a model.

@JoelDavidHamkins, Ah! OK, I'll correct it.

Interpreting ZFC is equivalent to interpreting ZFC+V=L, since L is definable in ZFC and so every interpreted model of ZFC also interprets a model of ZFC+V=L. Your theory doesn't seem to have its own L (unless this is really what you are asking?), so I think the L angle of your second question is irrelevant.

It seems delicate to interpret ZFC in your theory, since the interpreted model will have Dedekind infinite sets, but to prevent those sets from giving rise to actual Dedekind infinite sets will mean that the interpretation must be using an equivalence relation (i.e. interpreting = nontrivially).
